# `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, concatenate, Conv3DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout,  Lambda
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

Shape of my image is (36,128,128,1).How to change the shape of u7 so that I can perform concatenation?How to modify this?

```
def simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS, num_classes):
    #Build the model
        inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
        #s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)   #No need for this if we normalize our inputs beforehand
        s = inputs
        inputs = Input(shape=(36,128,128),name='input')
        #Contraction path
        c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(s)
        c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
        c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c1)
        p1 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c1)
        
        c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p1)
        c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
        c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c2)
        p2 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c2)
         
        c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p2)
        c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
        c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c3)
        p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c3)
         
        c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p3)
        c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
        c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c4)
        p4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(c4)
         
        c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p4)
        c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
        c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c5)
        
        #Expansive path 
        u6 = Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
        u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
        c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u6)
        c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
        c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c6)
         
        u7 = Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
        u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
        c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u7)
        c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
        c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c7)
         
        u8 = Conv3DTranspose(32, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
        u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
        c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u8)
        c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
        c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c8)
         
        u9 = Conv3DTranspose(16, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
        u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
        c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u9)
        c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
        c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c9)
         
        outputs = Conv3D(num_classes, (1, 1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)
         
        model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
        #compile model outside of this function to make it flexible. 
        model.summary()
        
        return model
```

I'm getting error in line u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])

A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 32, 32, 8, 64), (None, 32, 32, 9, 64)]
But if the Shape of my image is (64,128,128,1).It works properly.But if i increase the depth from 36 to 64;the image is changed

Building the model

```
epochs = 10
model.fit(
    X_train,y_train,
    validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
    epochs=epochs,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks = callbacks_list)
```

I'm getting error
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 36, 128, 128, 1), found shape=(None, 64, 128, 128, 1)

Comment: added import code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try concatenating on `axis=1` and removing one of your two `Input` layers. You only need one. Here is a working example (although I am not sure what your goal is):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, concatenate, Conv3DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout,  Lambda
import tensorflow as tf

def simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS, num_classes):
    #Build the model
        kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
        inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS), name='input')
        #s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)   #No need for this if we normalize our inputs beforehand
        s = inputs
        #Contraction path
        c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(s)
        c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
        c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c1)
        p1 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c1)
        
        c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p1)
        c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
        c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c2)
        p2 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c2)
         
        c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p2)
        c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
        c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c3)
        p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c3)
         
        c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p3)
        c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
        c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c4)
        p4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(c4)
         
        c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p4)
        c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
        c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c5)
        
        #Expansive path 
        u6 = Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
        u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
        c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u6)
        c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
        c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c6)
         
        u7 = Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
        u7 = concatenate([u7, c3], axis=1)
        c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u7)
        c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
        c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c7)
         
        u8 = Conv3DTranspose(32, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
        u8 = concatenate([u8, c2], axis=1)
        c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u8)
        c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
        c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c8)
         
        u9 = Conv3DTranspose(16, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
        u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=1)
        c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u9)
        c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
        c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c9)
         
        outputs = Conv3D(num_classes, (1, 1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)
         
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
        #compile model outside of this function to make it flexible. 
        model.summary()
        
        return model


simple_unet_model(36,128,128, 1, 5)
```

Comment: How to remove input layer

Comment: thanks a lot.sorry for the duplicate layer.but when it build it .it shows error.question updated

Comment: @user please do not ask a new question with new details after your original issue was resolved. Kindly close this issue and ask a new question. It is free. Think about other users that stumble across the same issue in the title of your question and then cannot figure out what the fix is because it is mixed with other questions.

Comment: Ok I think you have to wait a bit before you can ask a question again..@user Did you maybe ask a lot of questions and delete them afterwards? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273741/stack-overflow-you-have-reached-your-question-limit. Anyway, you just need to make sure that your model's input shape has the same shape as your data.

Comment: input shape is same.
    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 140, 128, 128, 1) vs (None, 36, 128, 128, 1))

Comment: Model parameters give:(None, 36, 128, 128, 1)
(None, 140, 128, 128, 1)/I dont have idea to modify it

Comment: after step u9 the shape is changed to 140

Comment: You will have to redesign your architecture if you want it to fit to your data

Comment: You can ask a new specific question on what problem you are facing but you should try by yourself first

Comment: axis=-1 .but the concatenation shapes are different at u7